# what does the following expression/statement mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what does the following statement mean?

$|m|=m$

$|m|$ denotes modulus of $m$

NOTE:$|-2|=2$

Comment: The statement $|m| = m$ is equivalent to $m \geq 0$. Since by definition
$$|m| := \begin{cases}m \quad &\text{ if } m \geq 0\\-m \quad &\text{ if } m < 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: You can also view it as the distance between the number and $0$. This interpretation is very nice for intuition. In general, in the set of reals, $|a-b|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$. In fact taking the set of all reals and taking function $d(a,b) = |a-b|$, $ (\mathbb{R},d)$ is a metric space. Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Examples_of_metric_spaces

Comment: You should give the context in which you found this.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite: are you trying to get the OP lost ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm trying to give the OP food for thought. OP seems genuinely interested in mathematics, so there's no harm in presenting things in a bigger context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment, but I can't comment because I have less than the reputation needed. What is the problem you trying to solve where such a condition appeared?
From other answers you gave to other questions I see that you perfectly know what a modulus is and how to deal with simple condition like this one. Try to argue better your difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

$$|m|=m$$ can be seen as an equation in $m$, the solution of which is

$$m\ge0$$ in the reals.

---

In the complex,

$$\Re(m)\ge0,\\\Im(m)=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

The modulus of a number is its absolute value (i.e - the magnitude without any signs).

This means that the modulus of -2 and 2, for example, is the same, because 2 and -2 have the same magnitude.

i.e.

$|-2| = 2$

$|2| = 2$

What other users have been saying is also very interesting; the idea that when we take the modulus of a number, we are effectively finding the 'distance' between that number and 0.

Comment: In what way does this answer the question ?

Comment: Hi, I understand your point - the examples appear to just repeat what was stated in the question. I'll sort this out now. Thanks for raising this.